# jQuery HTML validate sub form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have one form that contains additional sub forms (contained as divs) for example:

```
<form method="post" action="/process" id="form">
  <div id="initForm">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Please enter your name" />
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Please enter your email" />
    <button class="next">Continue</button>
  </div>
  <div class="subForm">
    <input type="text" name="jobPosition" placeholder="Please enter your job position" />
    <input type="text" name="jobCompany" placeholder="Please enter your company" /> 
    <button class="next">Continue</button>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

I want to use the `validate` plugin for the form, so whenever someone presses on `next` I want to validate this particular part of this form it validates before it lets you continue. I am therefore wondering is this possible to do this? I have used the below, but this is not doing anything. It gives no errors and is not validating the form. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

```
$("form#initForm").validate({
  rules: { 
    name: "required", 
  }, 
  messages: {
    name: "Please enter a valid name"
  }
});
```

Comment: Why the `$('form#initForm")`?

Comment: `But this is not doing anything, giving no errors` Are you sure there's no errors? As you can see from the syntax highlighting you've got mis-matched quotes

Comment: @Ionut Now thinking about this, this would only work with forms that have the ID of this. I just assumed that it's contained within `form`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your id of the `form` is different of the one you use in jQuery and the `$('form#form")` should be either `$('form#form')` or `$("form#form")`.

See the working snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#form').validate({
    rules: {
      name: "required",
      jobPosition: "required"
    },
    messages: {
      name: "Please enter a valid name",
      jobPosition: "Please enter a valid job"
    }
  });
  $('.next').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().find('input:first').valid();
  });
});
```

```css
label.error{
  color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="" id="form">

  <div id="initForm">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Please enter your name" />
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Please enter your email" />
    <button class="next">Continue</button>
  </div>

  <div class="subForm">
    <input type="text" name="jobPosition" placeholder="Please enter your job position" />
    <input type="text" name="jobCompany" placeholder="Please enter your company" />
    <button class="next">Continue</button>
  </div>


  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The issue is that it needs to validate when the user clicks on the `Continue` button rather than when they submit. This is because the form goes onto multiple pages

Comment: @Phorce, you can check if the inputs are valid on click of the `button` using `$('#form').valid();` See the updated answer.